# javascript prototype overriding a method calls the base method

Tags: javascript

I have three objects extending each other. Base - > A -> childA. They all have a method test in the prototype. When I call A.test or childA.test the Base.test is called. I wonder what are the options each object to call its own method. Here is the code:

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    function Base(){

    };

    Base.prototype.test = function(){
         console.log("base");   
    };

    function A(){

    };

    A.prototype.test = function(){
        console.log("A");   
    };

    function ChildA(){

    };

    ChildA.prototype.test = function(){
        console.log("ChildA");   
    };

    var base = new Base();

    var a = new A();

    var childA = new ChildA();

    $.extend( a, base );

    $.extend( childA, a );

    a.test();

    childA.test();
}
);
```

and fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/pjWjy/84/

So when I call `base.test - > log base; a.test -> log a; childA -> log childA;`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's not really how you do prototypical inheritance with constructor functions in JavaScript (it's not inheritance at all, just copying methods between instances). With any of the standard inheritance patterns, you'd be getting the right `test`.

Here's an example:

```js
// On old browsers like IE8, we need to shim Object.create
if (!Object.create) {
  Object.create = function(proto, props) {
    if (typeof props !== "undefined") {
      throw "The second argument of Object.create cannot be polyfilled";
    }
    function ctor() { }
    ctor.prototype = proto;
    return new ctor();
  };
}

// Define our Base constructor
function Base() {
}

// Define Base#test
Base.prototype.test = function() {
  snippet.log("Base#test");
};

// Derive A from Base
function A() {
  Base.call(this);
}
A.prototype = Object.create(Base.prototype);
A.prototype.constructor = A;

// Define A#test
A.prototype.test = function() {
  snippet.log("A#test");
};

// Derive ChildA from A
function ChildA() {
  A.call(this);
}
ChildA.prototype = Object.create(A.prototype);
ChildA.prototype.constructor = ChildA;

// Define ChildA#test
ChildA.prototype.test = function() {
  snippet.log("ChildA#test");
};

// Run
var b = new Base();
b.test();
var a = new A();
a.test();
var ca = new ChildA();
ca.test();
```

```html
<!-- Script provides the `snippet` object, see http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/242144/134069 -->
<script src="http://tjcrowder.github.io/simple-snippets-console/snippet.js"></script>
```

If you're going to be doing a lot of inheritance like this with constructor functions, you might be interested in my helper script [`Lineage`](http://code.google.com/p/lineagejs/), which makes things more concise and well-contained, and simplifies "supercalls" (chaining to the parent's version of a method). But of course, that script will be outdated soon by ES6's `class` feature.